# Dark notification on Android 10 with Remote View

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, android-10.0, android-remoteview

Getting Dark (black) notification as per image shown here when I changed display mode to Dark in Android 10. I tried to change text color but it is not reflating. I am using Remote view to create custom notification. How to change remote content view text colors different for Dark mode and light mode? Here is my code:

```
        val contentViewBig = RemoteViews(context.applicationContext.packageName, R.layout.design_custom_notification)
        contentViewBig.setTextViewText(R.id.tvNotificationTitle, notificationTitle)
        contentViewBig.setTextViewText(R.id.tvNotificationBody, notificationBody)

        val nId = Random().nextInt()

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                nId /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        val channelId = context.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
        val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setCustomContentView(contentViewBig)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setLights(Color.WHITE, 2000, 3000)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)


        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    context.resources.getString(R.string.app_name), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            channel.description = context.resources.getString(R.string.app_name)
            channel.setShowBadge(true)
            channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
            notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.notify(nId, notificationBuilder.build())
            wakeLockScreen(context)
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved problem by creating **values-night** folder. I have added colors.xml inside **values-night** folder and override colors which I have used in normal **values - colors.xml** and applying text color in remote view design file.

Ref. https://medium.cobeisfresh.com/how-to-implement-day-night-mode-in-your-android-app-2f21907f9b0a

**UPDATE:**

One more thing to prevent from latest `Xiaomi devices` forces dark app design while you are in dark mode.

Apply below parameter in `theme.xml` to your main theme style.

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
```

Comment: yes we can change txt colours from complete background color dose not get reflect. Still I am getting white background .